# AngularJs one time binding and order of values with boolean operators

Tags: javascript, angularjs, boolean-operations, one-time-binding

What impact does the order in which boolean operators are declared have?

Controller:

```
$scope.show = false;

$scope.clickMe = function() {
  $scope.show = true;
  $scope.name = 'Name defined'
};
```

Template:

```
<button ng-click="clickMe($event)">Click Me</button>
<p ng-if="::(show && name)">show && name</p>
<p ng-if="::(name && show)">name && show</p>
```

Results in the second `p` element with the order of `name && show` displaying after clicking button. I understood that neither `p` element should display as `$scope.show` is already defined and one time binding has been used?

plunkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/P0E1RhNK9EPh2Pi04c9T?p=preview

Comment: maybe because $scope.name was not defined yet ? What about if you init $scope.name to 'name undefined' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Angular, one time binding will constantly evaluate the expression until it has a non-`undefined` value. So in your example, because name is not defined yet `name && show` constantly evaluates as `undefined` on every digest until you finally set it. If you use `!!` to coerce name to a boolean then you'll get different behaviour. From the [Angular docs on expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

> One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable,
>   which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a
>   non-undefined value (see value stabilization algorithm below).

So it doesn't evaluate once per se, it evaluates *to a value* once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess this is more of a general javascript question. Why does `name && show === undefined` and not `show && name`

Comment: The `&&` operator doesn't evaluate to a boolean, if the left hand side is falsey then it returns that, otherwise it will return the right hand side. So `undefined && false` is `undefined` while `false && undefined` is `false`. If `name` in your example was `''` instead, then both `::(name && show)` and `::(show && name)` would have the same behaviour.

Comment: The [MDN docs for logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) are very thorough and a lot better than my explanation as well.